# AttributeError: type object 'EnglishDefaults' has no attribute 'create_tokenizer'

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, spacy, attributeerror

```
import os
import torch
import numpy as np
import random
import spacy
from bpemb import BPEmb
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
tokenizer = nlp.Defaults.create_tokenizer(nlp)
```

This is my code and whenever I try to run this an error shows up saying

```
AttributeError: type object 'EnglishDefaults' has no attribute 'create_tokenizer'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using the build-in Class `Tokenizer` that, according to the [documentation](https://spacy.io/api/tokenizer#init), we can use to create new tokenizer?

```py
import spacy
from spacy.tokenizer import Tokenizer
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
tokenizer = Tokenizer(nlp.vocab)
print(tokenizer)
```

result:

```bash
$ python3 main.py
<spacy.tokenizer.Tokenizer object at 0x13e7a52d0>
```